# AndroidStudio : ListView and TabActivity

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application using android studio

Main_Activity is a splash screen. 
Home_Activity is a TabActivity contains 3 tabs to three different forms one of them is a list activity

I have created a List_Activity that contains a list view , so I have set the activity type to ListActivity .

my problem is : when I start my app on my phone it gives errors

> *1:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Componentinfo{com.example.discopc.myapp/com.example.discopc.myapp.List1}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: your content must have a ListView Whose Id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'*

I have searched on Internet but didn't find any good answer.

The List_Activity will work fine if I Start it as a single app W/o other activities.

But when I use my splash screen and TabActivity app crash.

**I have tried :**

Using only List activity form but it starts normally ! 
I don't know why it won't start with my splash screen & tabview

Changing name of listview in List_activity

doing : android:id="@android:id/list" in XML files

**--------------------------------------------------------------**

```
 public ListView list;
```

**CODE : OnCreate of List1 Activity :**

```
  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    deletbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.deletbox);
    final ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.deletbox)).isChecked();
    //Write1("*192.16834.0.1405:88839@ok^avvali$rele1#" + "*192.168.0.105:8889@ok^dovomi$rele2#" + "*192.168.1.9:12@no^seeee$rele3#");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    //listItems.add("New Item");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //loadlist();
```

**CODE : TabActivity (Home) Code that Gives Error :**

*This code works fine with other ActionBar Activity Forms*

```
   try {
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list"); // Create a new TabSpec using tab host
        spec.setIndicator("LIST"); // set the “LIST” as an indicator
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent(this, List1.class);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1:"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        // Do the same for the other tabs
```

it always Toast

*1:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
Componentinfo{com.example.discopc.myapp/com.example.discopc.myapp.List1}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: your content must have a ListView Whose Id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'*

**HTML : of list activity**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="List"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width_overflow_material"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:longClickable="true">
    </ListView>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/deletbox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:checked="false" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Note :

- List1 , extend ListActivity

  Home , extends TabActivity

Its not a problem of Tabs cause it work fine with my other forms

> **Question : How to use SplashScreen and Tab View with a Listview ?**

Comment: `@android:id/list` will use the ID "list" from the package android . You should use custom Listview

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated . Search on google

Comment: follow this link for tab layout https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/